# Why wfs source is downloaded as xml file, not displays spatial data on openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I wish to transform features from geoserver wfs to openlayers.
But a requests only downloads xml file with features, not displays a spatial data on openlayers map.
What is wrong in params of my layer or source?
WMS was got well, without problems.

```
const WfsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(
{
  source: new ol.source.Vector(
  {
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
     url: "http://www.mygisdomen.su/geoserver/wfs?&service=wfs&version=2.0.0&
           request=GetFeature&typeNames=wsname:layername"
  })
});
```

Comment: If you have XML data use `new ol.format.WFS()`.  To use new `ol.format.GeoJSON()`, if the server supports it, you would need to include `&outputFormat=application/json` in your url.  `ol.format.WFS()` does not automatically reproject from Lon/Lat to view projection and you would usually need a loader function.

Comment: ok, I have got json, but data doesn't displays

Comment: Are the JSON coordinates in Lon/Lat format or another projection?

Comment: @Mike another, it is 3857

Comment: You will need to specify that in the format `ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})` in OpenLayer 5 or if you are using an earlier version `ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})`

Comment: @Mike thanks, but nothing new. Data doesn't displays on map